# Android MVP pattern package structure

Tags: android, package, mvp

I saw various great tutorials on MVP pattern in android, but the authors all seem to have different practice on packaging.

The first tutorial I saw did the packaging by functionalities. Such as, "Login", "Join", "UI" package.

The UI package has only activities, the "Login" package has the interfaces for the presenter and the concrete presenter, and this package contains a sub package "Model" that contains everything about the login model(communications with the server). The "Join" package has the same composition as the "Login" package.

But the other one I saw did the packaging by scene, such as "Join", "Login".

"Join" package contains an activity, and three sub packages named "Model", "View", "Presenter".

What is the best practice? Are there any articles that handles this issue?

Comment: Is it a real issue for you? It's more of the matter of style/convention.

Comment: Well, I'm just looking for the best practice.

Comment: Personally I'd split by models, presenters and views in manner of splitting by services, repositories, utilities and so forth. I develop a pet cross-platform MVP framework, and I prefer the above style. Say, models and presenters are cross-platform, but their respective views use a different, "more platform-dependent", package (e.g. foo.app.core and foo.app.android or foo.app.gwt respectively). However, other people may prefer another style, and that's justified.

Comment: take a look at this article and sample project which might help:
https://medium.com/@m_mirhoseini/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21#.6y9ze7e55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just repost my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810785/android-mvp-which-layer-should-store-context-variable/40826241#40826241)

I often put business logic code in **Model Layer** (don't make confusion with model in database). I often rename as `XManager` for avoiding confusion (such as `ProductManager`, `MediaManager` ...) so presenter class just uses for keeping workflow.

The rule of thumb is no or at least limit **import android package** in presenter class. This best practice supports you easier in testing presenter class because presenter now is just a plain java class, so we don't need android framework for testing those things.

For example here is my mvp workflow.

**View class**: This is a place you store all your view such as button, textview ... and you set all listeners for those view components on this layer. Also on this View, you define a Listener class for presenter implements later. Your view components will call methods on this listener class.

```
class ViewImpl implements View {
   Button playButton;
   ViewListener listener;

   public ViewImpl(ViewListener listener) {
     // find all view

     this.listener = listener;

     playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       listener.playSong();
     });
   }

   public interface ViewListener {
     playSong();
   }
}
```

**Presenter class:** This is where you store view and model inside for calling later. Also presenter class will implement ViewListener interface has defined above. Main point of presenter is control logic workflow.

```
class PresenterImpl extends Presenter implements ViewListener {
    private View view;
    private MediaManager mediaManager;

    public PresenterImpl(View, MediaManager manager) {
       this.view = view;
       this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void playSong() {
       mediaManager.playMedia();
    }
}
```

**Manager class:** Here is the core business logic code.  Maybe one presenter will have many managers (depend on how complicate the view is). Often we get `Context` class through some injection framework such as `Dagger`.

```
Class MediaManagerImpl extends MediaManager {
   // using Dagger for injection context if you want
   @Inject
   private Context context;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

   // dagger solution
   public MediaPlayerManagerImpl() {
     this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(context);
   }

   // no dagger solution
   public MediaPlayerManagerImpl(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
     this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(context);
   }

   public void playMedia() {
     mediaPlayer.play();
   }

   public void stopMedia() {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
   }
}
```

**Finally:** Put those thing together in Activities, Fragments ... Here is the place you initialize view, manager and assign all to presenter.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   Presenter presenter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      IView view = new ViewImpl();
      MediaManager manager = new   MediaManagerImpl(this.getApplicationContext());
      // or this. if you use Dagger
      MediaManager manager = new   MediaManagerImpl();
      presenter = new PresenterImpl(view, manager);
   }   

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     presenter.onStop();
   }
}
```

You see that each presenter, model, view is wrapped by one interface. Those components will called through interface. This design will make your code more robust and easier for modifying later.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. It looks somewhat different from what I saw when I wrote this question. In that way, the view is just an interface without any impl classes but the activity or fragment. I find yours more interesting. But how do you deal with callbacks from the xManagers(model classes) after doing some thread stuffs? What if the presenter just needs to deliver it's result to the view class? How do you handle these situations?

Comment: about processing callback. it depends on situations. If the callback is simple (change only state variables ...), I can call directly on xManager. if it's complicate, i will make Listener interface on xManager (similar to View I have discussed above) and Presenter will implement this listener. so when callback is finished, xManager will call for example `listener.loginSuccess()` . (and `loginSuccess` will be implemented on presenter class through interface)

Comment: about presenter deliver result to view class. View class defines "dump method" such as: `setUsername(username)` or `disableLoginButton()` ... presenter will called those method. In case I want to change view through manager class, I will go through presenter class. In some cases it makes code redundant but in long term, it will make code has better structure.

Comment: Thanks again. I like the concept of your view impl. I think it will make my activity codes more simpler.

Answer (score 16):

> App should have package according to `features` not by the common
>   functionality.

I find people make activity, fragments, Adapters,etc. 
common purpose package in one group but this is **bad practice**!

*Mostly developers group them like this because they do this to keep the same package structure for all the applications they work on*. But that is very wrong decision cause it is always hard to find classes when they are grouped only because they share same parent classes!

> We should group the classes according to parent classes but only if
>   we are making some API but if we are making a custom product for our
>   client then it is very bad practice.!

Like all activities most developers put in activity package because all activity classes extends the Activity class.That makes sense that this is only activity related package but it is hard to go through those packages.

Suppose we have One OrderListActivity class and we fetch the order list from server and then display it in one OrderListFragment class and obviously for that we need OrderListAdapter to show the order listing. so when customer ask for some modification or any feature he wants on that Order List screen we have to go to many packages to satisfy client need. Like we have to go to activity package and modify some thing in OrderListActivity and then go to OrderListFragment and then OrderListAdapter and then OrderListViewHolder,etc.!So This becomes too hard and we may create issues in process of modifying!

> so we should group together the classes which are getting
>   changed/modify together.

That's the best practice and so we should group all those classes who are responsible for OrderListing feature in one package and we call it orderdlist package.

Please check my this medium post i have explained the package structure too in that:--

> https://medium.com/@kailash09dabhi/mvp-with-better-naming-of-implementation-classes-dry-principle-e8b6130bbd02

Answer (score 4):

The good practice is to separate stuffs by feature (sometimes considered as module) and layer, not by their role. Reason: class/interface name already told that, e.g LoginView, LoginPresenter, LoginFragment, LoginActivity etc.

Comment: I never had witnessed any theory about packaging before. Are there any reference that I can look on?